# layout_margin not inherited from included ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

So I have two files:

```
where_include_happens.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/hours"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="60dp">

    <include android:id="@+id/some_id" 
        layout="@layout/whats_included"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And

```
whats_included.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/some_description"
    android:src="@drawable/some_awesome_drawable"  />
```

My problem is that each one of those elements should have `android:layout_margin="6dp"` parameter, but it seems to be ignored by include :(. Only thing in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html), that I find related is:

> **Caution:** If you want to override layout attributes using the  tag, you must override both android:layout_height and android:layout_width in order for other layout attributes to take effect.

My question is:

**Is there something I'm not seeing, or am I condemned to write `android:layout_margin="6dp"` in every single include in my project?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your include.xml consists of a single ImageView only you can, instead of using include directive, define a style for your ImageView and apply that style as needed.

Comment: Wow! That's utterly great! I'm new to android and I wasn't aware that kind of mechanism even exists in API! That solved many of my other problems as well, thanks! +1